# ng-select not updating hard listed default option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-select

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get the correct option selected based on the data coming back from the service.  the "rides" is returning just fine and the div is getting displayed properly, but my `<select>` is not updating or displaying the proper predetermined filter method (same thing for another select for sorting).  The auto filter is happening in the service and simply returning the filter type when its done to be able to update the HTML select so it displays to the user what filter method was chosen.  but the SELECT is simply showing an undefined option.

The console print out in the service prints "[], undefined, undefined" which tells me that is executing before the promise is fully returned.  However, once the promise is fully returned, $scope.rides IS getting defined as the DIV populates just fine, so why isn't the SELECT getting a correct value passed to it?

HTML:

```
  <select id="rides_filterMenu" ng-model="filter" ng-change="doFilter(filter);">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="standard">Sedan</option>
  <option value="suv">SUV</option>
  <option value="limo">Limo</option>        
  </select>
<div ng-repeat="ride in rides">
    {{ride.name}} is a {{ride.type}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('RidesCtrl', function($scope,$interval,Rides,constants) {
    [$scope.rides,$scope.filter,$scope.sort] = Rides.all();
```

Service:

```
.factory('Rides', function($http,$q,servicesA,servicesB,servicesC,servicesD,servicesE,serviceF) {
  var rides=[] ;
  var rideFilter;
  var rideSort ;

  function sortRides(sortBy) {
    // sort "rides" here before sending back to controller
  }
  function filterRides(filterBy) {
     // filter "rides" here before sending back to controller
  }
  function getRides() {
    rides = [] ;
    var rideCount = 0 ;

    $q.all([servicesA(),servicesB(),servicesC(),servicesD(),servicesE(),servicesF()]).then(function(response){
      var z=0 ;
      for (var y=0;y<response.length;y++) {
        for (var x=0;x<response[y].length;x++) { 
          response[y][x].rideID = z++ ;
          rides.push(response[y][x]) ;
          if (response[y][x].isType == 1 || response[y][x].isType == 2) {
            rideCount++ ;
          }
        }
      }

      //tInfo is a global var/obj
      if (rideSort) {
        sortRides(rideSort) ;
      } else {
        rideSort = getDB("userRidesSort") ;
        sortRides(rideSort) ;
      }

      if (rideCount < 7) {
        // override default filter if not enough services to show
        rideFilter = "all" ;
        filterRides(rideFilter) ;    
      } else {
        if (tInfo.totalRiders > 7) {
          // override default filter if too many passengers
          rideFilter = "limo" ;          
        } else if (tInfo.filterManual == 1) {
          // do nothing
        } else {
          // if not set, get it and set it.
          rideFilter = getDB("userRidesFilter") ;
        }
        filterRides(rideFilter) ;
      }
      // prints to console with correct values
      console.log("filter: "+rideFilter+ ", sort: " +rideSort) ;
    });
  }

  getRides() ;

  return {
    all: function() {
      // initially prints "[], undefined : undefined"
      // but when $q finishes $scope.rides populates the UI View
      // while $scope.filter & $scope.sort never update the UI View
      console.log(rides+ "," +rideFilter + " : " +rideSort) ;
      return [rides,rideFilter,rideSort] ;
    }
```

above `console.log`, rides initially returns [], but then when $q is finished i can see rides[] is populated and template View is updated (already properly sorted/filterd).  rideFilter and rideSort also initially return `undefined` in that same console.log, but even after rides UI is updated, $scope.filter and $scope.sort stay blank. On the 1st call into the service Rides this happens every time...but if I manually refresh Rides from the UI View, before $q even kicks off all the promises a 2nd time, I then see $scope.filter and $scope.sort populate the UIView- which tells me the values are there from the 1st call and they are now retrieved from cache as the 2nd call kicks in but before it fully updates/changes all the values..

Comment: You said `console print out in the service prints "[], undefined, undefined" `. Are `rides, rideFilter, rideSort` are hardcoded in service? You have also mentioned about `promise`, but I don't see that you have used any promises. Can you update question with more code from your controller and service..

Comment: Please put your code plunker

Comment: where is defined the doFilter function?

Comment: doFilter() is defined in the controller...works fine, and is only called when the user changes the filter option.  The issue above though is that I can't get $scope.filter to update the pre-selected (from the service) filter method.  The initial page load shows the filter `<select> as empty (or `undefined`).  After that, the page will auto refresh on its own and then the $scope.filter will appear selected in the options.  Its the initial page load that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a small change (supposing the filter is the ride type):

removes the event on select:

```
<select id="rides_filterMenu" ng-model="filter">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="standard">Sedan</option>
    <option value="suv">SUV</option>
    <option value="limo">Limo</option>        
</select>
```

and then, filter directly on ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="ride in rides | filter: { type: filter}">
    {{ride.name}} is a {{ride.type}}
</div>
```